# Restricting SSRS subscriptions to shared schedules only

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I'm reasonably new to SQL Server Reporting Services and Report Manager, and completely new to SSRS's Subscriptions. We're running SSRS 2008.

Out of the box it seems that a user with the Browser role can create a Subscription to a report and schedule it to run at any time they choose.

As an admin I have setup a schedule called "Overnight reports" and have it run every night from 1am.

I would like it so that when a regular user creates their Subscription they can **only** use one of my shared schedules so that their subscription will only run overnight.

Is this possible?

Thanks

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

No SSRS does not support this level of granularity with its security model.

I entered this connect feature request awhile back, please upvote it if you think it would be useful:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=458776

Answer (score 0):

You can create the report so it generates from a snapshot - under execution options "Render this report from a report execution snapshot"